# Google appengine in multitenancy application creates single instance and do not allow other tenant once set

Tags: java, google-app-engine, namespaces, google-cloud-endpoints, multi-tenant

In multitenant application instance is created once the namespace is set when other user tries to access the app through different instance actions are performed excepts from entries having common name.

> Example: if i log into app with namespace country1 and then try to login with country2 user from country2 and country 1 who have same key say john when tries to login its credentials are checked with as of country1 hence it gives wrong password.
>   If tried to login by user which is only in country2 login is success but now if comman key are searched they give result that of country1

Overall once one namespace is set search command give result in favor of namespace which was set earlier.Instead of namespace who should give results independent of each other.

thanks in advance.any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application i have a scenario of superadmin who can view all namespaces hence i need to set them according to request. My issue is resolved now as I was setting namespace after calling getPersistentManger() so it was causing the problem, after shifting NamespaceManger.set at first line of call, and then calling persistent manager, application is working fine:)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details or perhaps share some code here? Where are you setting the namespace?

In general, you need to set the namespace as soon as you get a request. If you are using Java, for example, you should do that using a Filter. After setting the namespace, all requests operations are going to use this namespace seamlessly. I don't understand why would you need to change that, but if you really need to do that, I don't see a problem... although you should be really careful because this approach may lead to a very confusing and buggy situation.

I think the namespace definition is valid only for a single request, so you should have a mechanism to redefine it every single time.

cheers!

Comment: In my application i have a scenario of superadmin who can view all namespaces hence i need to set them according to request. My issue is resolved now as I was setting namespace after calling `getPersistentManger()` so it was causing the problem, after shifting `NamespaceManger.set` at first line of call, and then calling persistent manager, application is working fine:)